# how to make serialize values in column depends on another coloumn

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, linq

[image: [my table]]

I want to know how can i make the values in this bordered column in this table be increment when INVOICE_ITEM_ID column = 14 and when it change to 15 the value in the bordered table start from 1 again and increment with the next 1 and so on

Comment: `Mysql` <> `Sql Server` which one are you really using ?

Comment: If value of InvoiceNumber will be same for INVOICE_ITEM_ID then we should create a new table with these 2 columns.

Comment: You tagged this question as c#. MySQL, sql, and linq. It is hard to give a good answer if it isn't clear what language you are working in. Do you have any code where you have tried to accomplish this? Or are you trying to do this on a database? Or in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `SQL SERVER`, you are looking for `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT  
InvoiceNumber,
INVOICE_ITEM_ID,
SerialNumber,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INVOICE_ITEM_ID ORDER BY SerialNumber) AS RowNumber
FROM    table_name
ORDER   BY INVOICE_ITEM_ID,SerialNumber
```